# Show input field of a form according to the value of dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which contains a dropdown and 2 other input fields.Initially I want to show only the dropdown and hide other two fields and show the other two fields when the value of dropdown is other.

```
<form id="submit_form" name="myform" action="/download" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
  <fieldset>
    <select name="one" onchange="if (this.value=='other'){this.form['datefrom'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['datefrom'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">Select...</option>
            <option value = "1m" >1 month</option>
            <option value = "2m">2 months</option>
            <option value = "3m">3 months</option>
            <option value = "other">other</option>
    </select>
    <br> From:
    <br>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="datefrom"><br> To:
    <br>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="dateto"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

In my code initially all the input fields are showing.So if anybody could me how to hide and the two datetime input fields initially and show them only when the value of dropdown is other.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We would gladly provide help if you show us that you are trying to help yourself. You can show us by posting some code which you have tried to achieve the same.

Comment: Well I have posted the code.I tried this if (this.value=='other'){this.form['datefrom'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['datefrom'].style.visibility='hidden'} but doesn't hides the  input box initially and only hides it when I select some value.

Comment: @Miller, That is because those events would be triggered only on change of select boxes. You can use `document.ready` to set the initial states of input boxes as hidden. or when designing the HTML itself you can add `style` attribute to hide the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript.
First, you set your input field as hidden who warp inside div.
Use `onchange` for dynamic condition based on your select option value.

Check this example.

```js
function func(value) {
  if (value == 'other') {
    $('#input_field').show();
  } else {
    $('#input_field').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="submit_form" name="myform" action="/download" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
  <fieldset>
    <select name="one" onchange="func(this.value)">
      <option value="none" selected="selected">Select...</option>
      <option value="1m">1 month</option>
      <option value="2m">2 months</option>
      <option value="3m">3 months</option>
      <option value="other">other</option>
    </select>
    <div id="input_field" style="display:none;">
      <br> From:
      <br>
      <input type="datetime-local" name="datefrom"><br> To:
      <br>
      <input type="datetime-local" name="dateto"><br><br>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript solution**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.cs-hide{
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
   <option value = "1m" >1 month</option>
  <option value = "2m">2 months</option>
  <option value = "3m">3 months</option>
  <option value = "other">other</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="dateContainer" class="cs-hide">
   From:<br>
  <input type="datetime-local" name="datefrom"><br>
   To:<br>
  <input type="datetime-local" name="dateto"><br><br>
</div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">


<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  var element = document.getElementById("dateContainer");
  if(x === "other"){
    element.classList.remove("cs-hide");
  }else{
    element.classList.add("cs-hide");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so u added javascript tag so i gave this solution @miller